# Method error in Julia when using Parameters.jl

Tags: julia

I want to define variables as below, but does not when I add the line `time::Vector{Float32}=[a:step:b]`
using Parameters

```
@with_kw mutable struct variables
 InetrpolationDegree::Int = 1
        a::Float32 =0.0
        b::Float32 =15.0
        N::Int = 100
     step::Float32 = (b-a)/N
        time::Vector{Float32}=[a:step:b]
end

t=variables(N=100).time;
Δt=variables(N=100).step;
s=variables(N=100).InetrpolationDegree
```

I got this this error

> MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type StepRangeLen{Float64,
> Base.TwicePrecision{Float64}, Base.TwicePrecision{Float64}, Int64} to
> an object of type Float32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be aware that the constructed object through `a:step:b` is subtype of the `AbstractRange` AbstractType. So wrapping it within brackets `[a:step:b]` won't make an object of type `Vector{Float32}`! Thus, you should declare the correct type within braces. Since the returned object is a `Vector`, which in the element is an object `<:AbstractRange` (read it: subtype of AbstractRange), we can say:
`time::Vector{<:AbstractRange}=[a:step:b]`

```
@with_kw mutable struct variables
  InetrpolationDegree::Int = 1
  a::Float32 =0.0
  b::Float32 =15.0
  N::Int = 100
  step::Float32 = (b-a)/N
  time::Vector{<:AbstractRange}=[a:step:b]
end;

t=variables(N=100).time;
Δt=variables(N=100).step;
s=variables(N=100).InetrpolationDegree # returns 1
```

## Additional Note

Keep in mind that you can also use `Base.@kwdef` rather than `@with_kw`.

Comment: Gteat! Thank you @Shayan I agree with you `Base.@kwdef`, I think at the two commands are the same?

Comment: @HarizKhaled, YW! In this example, yes, both can be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem appears to be that you are wrapping your range-object in brackets, `[]`. That turns it into a Vector of ranges, which may not be what you actually want. Changing the field signature to

```
time::Vector{<:AbstractRange}=[a:step:b]
```

removes the error but has some unfortunate side effects. Firstly, you now have a vector of ranges, instead of just a plain range. Secondly, the field is now *abstractly* typed, which is bad for performance.

I suggest these two alternatives instead:

Fix the type signature and remove the brackets:

```
@with_kw mutable struct Variables
    InterpolationDegree::Int = 1  # this field was mis-spelled
    a::Float32 = 0.0f0  # using literal float syntax (not strictly necessary)
    b::Float32 = 15.0f0
    N::Int = 100
    step::Float32 = (b-a)/N
    Time::StepRangeLen{Float32,Float64,Float64,Int64} = (a:step:b)
end
```

Or, collect the vector and fix the signature:

```
@with_kw mutable struct Variables
    InterpolationDegree::Int = 1
    a::Float32 = 0.0f0
    b::Float32 = 15.0f0
    N::Int = 100
    step::Float32 = (b-a)/N
    Time::Vector{Float32} = collect(a:step:b)
end
```

I prefer the first alternative, if possible, since it uses a lightweight range, instead of a `Vector` which wastes memory, especially for long time-intervals.

Two more remarks:

1. By convention, type names should be capitalized: `Variables`, not `variables`.
2. Are you sure that your struct needs to be `mutable`? Immutable structs have better performance, and can be safer from accidental mutation.